# How to connect/disconnect an Ethernet network with command line

Tags: macos, networking, command-line, ethernet

I am using a balanced IP at work but some servers don't like that, they are considering it a security breach, so i often need to switch from my Ethernet connection (balanced with 2 IPs), to a Wireless connection (only one IP).

Is there a command i can use to switch the Ethernet connection on/off for Mac OSX?

I was looking into the `networksetup` command but i couldn't find the right option.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: your simplest method would be to just down the interfaces you no longer want to be active: ifconfig <interface> down

Comment: @MaQleod is correct but this usually requires privileges so `sudo iconfig [interface]`

Comment: thanks to your precious comments, i was able to create two apps with AppleScript, one to end Ethernet connection, the other to reestablish it.

Answer (score 2):

Use AppleScript to create two apps, one to end Ethernet connection, the other to reestablish it.

this will end connection:

```
do shell script "/sbin/ifconfig en0 down" user name "username" password "password" with administrator privileges
```

this will reestablish it:

```
do shell script "/sbin/ifconfig en0 up" user name "username" password "password" with administrator privileges
```

use administrator credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Mauro I ended up logging in as an Admin User (which is my default) and used Terminal as follows -

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig en0 up
```

OR

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig en0 down
```